# Query selection based on group value

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using VB.net , Entity framework 6 with sql server 2008R2  , and I need help creating a query.
I have a table : MyTable1 that has a such structure :

```
ID.....group.........vl1
1........1...........7
2........1...........8
3........1...........3
4........2...........2
5........2...........4
```

I want to select only those rows for which the group's total value for vl1  is over 10.
For the example above we have :

```
Group=1  Vl1 ( total) = 7+8+3=18
Group=2  Vl1 ( total) = 2+4=6
```

So the value for group 1 is over 10 so all the rows that have group=1 should be selected. The value for the group2 is 6 so all the rows having group=2 should not be selected.

How can I construct a such query ?

Thank you !

Edited :
I try this query but is not working :

```
 Dim query as IEnumerable (OF MyTable)
 Query = From t In context.MyTables
         Group By t.group Into Group
         Select Group Where Group.Sum(Function(t2) t2.vl1) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, although maybe there is a better way to structure it:

```
Dim query =
    From t In context.MyTables
    Group By t.group Into g = Group
    Where g.Sum(Function(x) x.vl1) > 10
    From t2 In g
    Select t2
```

The `From t2 in g Select t2` part is doing a `SelectMany` for each of the groups that satisfied the `Where` clause.